# Call JavaScript from link button

Tags: asp.net

I develop a webpage in that the user want to call a JavaScript function. Based on what the function returns I want to continue the link button URL. I paste my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fvalidate()
    {
        var i = document.getElementById('txtvalue').value;
        if(i=='23')
        {
            Here I want to execute server side code
        }
        else
        {
            I want to show some alert message to the user and the page won't refresh.
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:LinkButton
    Width="35px"
    ID="updateUserL"
    runat="server"
    OnClick="updateForm_Click"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClientClick="fvalidate();"
>Update</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: i got answer , Thanks for help

Comment: Hey @Sakthivel:  When people say you should "accept" an answer, they mean that you must click on the check mark next to the one answer that  best answers your question.  Go back to each question you've ever asked and do that.  Otherwise, people will stop helping you (people want to be recognized for the help they give).

Comment: @Good Two Shoes: This question wouldn't have had a bounty when that comment was made.

Answer (score 20):

Modify your function as follows:

```
function fvalidate()
{
   var i = document.getElementById('txtvalue').value;
   if(i=='23') 
   {   
    return true;
   }
   else    
   { 
    prompt("Your Message");
    return false;
   }
}
```

And modify your OnClientClick so it reads `OnClientClick="return fvalidate();"`

Answer (score 3):

The OnClientClick should read somthing like

```
OnClientClick="javascript:return fvalidate();"
```

and then the function

```
function fvalidate()  
{  
   var i = document.getElementById('txtvalue').value;  
    if(i=='23') return true;  
else    return false;  
}
```

return true will then pass to the server side code.

Comment: You don't need to specify "javascript:" on the OnClientClick.